# Can I use the noun "making" instead of "product"?

Tags: word-usage

A maker makes products. So the products are the maker's makings. Is that correct?

Another way would be: A maker makes makings.

Comment: No,  “making” doesn’t mean “product.” https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/making

Comment: Why is my question down voted?

Comment: @nuiun Because you don't appear to have done any research for yourself. Did you look it up in a dictionary for example?

Comment: It's worth noting that, in BrE **makings** is used to describe the components needed to make something. For example "Do you have the makings for that cake?"  means "Do you have the necessary ingredients for that cake?" . It can apply to any project.

Comment: @Peter Jennings thank you for your note. That definitely helps clarify it for myself. I looked it up on dict.leo.org. In german we can simply make nouns out of any verb. After looking up "makings" I still was not sure if using the term as mentioned is allowed/understandable or not.
https://dict.leo.org/german-english/makings

Comment: @nuiun I forgot to mention that it can also be used in the sense of having potential. For example "Joe has the **makings** of a good pianist" means "Joe could become a good pianist". It usually implies that some work or study would be required before the possible goal is attained. It does not mean that the person **will** do something, just that he has the ability to do so. Joe might decide to become an accountant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use the noun "making" to mean "production". For example:

The making of cars = the production of cars